# Visual Studio Online continuous deploy ASP.NET web pages to Azure Websites without build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

How can I **continuous deploy** an ASP.NET web pages project to **Azure Websites**(Web App) without building it by hosted build controller(provided by **Visual Studio Online**)?

My project contains web pages and do not need to build in order to work. The web pages will be build dynamically when it is live. Also, I don't want to waste my build minutes in order to publish it since it is not required to build. However, I can't found any setting regarding this in Visual Studio. I had set up and wanted to use **continuous deployment** in Azure Websites.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If you install the Azure SDK stuff for Visual Studio you can publish directly to an Azure Website from Visual Studio. You don't need to run your build on a build server, just build locally. Left click on your web project then select "Publish..." then you should see a "Publish Web" wizard that lets you select your azure website and push your built to it.

Comment: How about if I want to use continuous deployment because continuous deployment provide a option such that we can redeploy the previous deployment easily in the Azure Portal if the current deployment failed?

Comment: Azure does support continuous deployment. I've used it with Visual Studio online, it works well. You just authorize Azure to get checkin notifications then it (or VS online) will build from source code and deploy to your Azure website in a Staging environment. This way you can smoke test your build in staging before swapping that with production. You can also revert that back if you find an issue in production. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/

Comment: Thanks for your info. How about if I want continuous deployment without building ? Can it just like normal deployment but it go through the VSO continuous deployment process without building?

Comment: I think the whole system is set up to build then deploy. However you can have your solution build pre-compiled stuff. Just get all your built things into the solution, the solution will "build" but the only thing happening is your binaries / static pages will get put into the bin or View directory, etc.